# Wordpress HTTPS redirect loop

Tags: redirect, wp-redirect

I've been struggling to get HTTPS functional on my site for over ten hours now. I've got severe headache trying to set it up myself. I want you to understand that I tried several different ways to solve and asking this amazing community only as a last resort. I would really appreciate if anyone could help me out.

The website is running on Apache and the conf file looks like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

**First Issue:**
After these changes to the conf file, I tried to reload the website and it throws an error. A redirect loop.

**Second issue:**
When I change the site and home urls in the general settings screen to https:// from http://, it leads to a redirect loop.

I just don't understand why these are happening. I tried different variations of htaccess rules. I played with the apache configurations. Nothing worked.

Let me know if you need any other information. All help is welcome. Thank you :)

Comment: I found the plugin [WordPress HTTPS](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-https/) works very well, no headaches!

Comment: I'm still getting 302 redirect loops with wordpress-https.

Comment: This is worth checking out ifor people behind a Load Balancer (e.g.: on Heroku) https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/220896/68251

Answer (score 6):

I'v added `$_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';` to my **wp-config.php** as seen on [WordPress wp-admin https redirect loop](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/170165/wordpress-wp-admin-https-redirect-loop) and it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

This appeared in WordPress 4.0.

It's reported in [Trac](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/29708) and will likely be fixed with the next version.

Meanwhile I'm trying a workaround by setting the WordPress Address (URL) to `http` and the Site Address (URL) to `https` at `/wp-admin/options-general.php`.