# Cannot login to Wordpress Admin with SSL terminated load balancer

Tags: admin, ssl

Running Wordpress 4.7.3 with a HAProxy (version 1.7.2) frontend and
Apache 2.4.10 with PHP 5.6 backend.

This is all under `Debian 8.7` as well.

`X-Forwarded-For` and `X-Forwarded-Proto` are set correctly by HAProxy.

The issue I'm having is when I have SSL terminated on the HAProxy frontend (running http mode) and login to Wordpress Admin I get the error

> Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page.

I tried the steps from [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/250240/setting-serverhttps-on-prevents-access-to-wp-admin) but they didn't fix the issue.

At the bottom of my `wp-config.php` I have

```
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
// in some setups HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO might contain
// a comma-separated list e.g. http,https
// so check for https existence
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') !== false)
       $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
```

I tried a clean install of Wordpress (was importing a clients side of an earlier Wordpress for spring cleaning, but that didn't fix the issue either).

Answer (score 7):

I just figured out the issue.

You need to add the HTTPS/SSL settings before `require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');` in your `wp-config.php`

So the relevant part of your `wp-config.php` should look like this.

```
define( 'FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true );

// in some setups HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO might contain
// a comma-separated list e.g. http,https
// so check for https existence
if( false !== strpos( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https' ) ) {
    $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
}

/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php' );
```

Comment: Adding the the code above the require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php' ); is very important or else it will not work

Comment: thanks for sharing, this should be added to the official documentation: https://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Over_SSL#Using_a_Reverse_Proxy