# HTTPS leads to Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page

Tags: errors, https, user-access

I have a fresh Wordpress installation that works fine. I decide to make it work under HTTPS so I go in the General config and change the "Wordpress Address" and the "Site Adress" from http://my.website.com/blog/ to https://my.website.com/blog/.

First, this create a redirection loop so I have to add the following lines to my wp_config.php:

```
/** SSL */  
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);  
// in some setups HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO might contain  
// a comma-separated list e.g. http,https  
// so check for https existence  
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') !== false)  
    $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
```

There, I'm able to see the blog in HTTPS as well as the login page. Once I try to login though, I get the following error: `Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page.`

Impossible to access to the admin interface in HTTPS.

If I reverse the URLs (via phpMyAdmin) and remove the lines from my wp_config.php file, I can login properly. Any idea what is wrong with my installation? Is it the fact that the blog is under /blog/?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is that a WordPress error message or an Nginx/Apache error message? Is this a single or a multisite install? Is your login page served over HTTPS?

Answer (score 14):

Just a quick note, the code

```
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https')
 $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
```

need to be at the top of the config file just after the `<php` or it will not work.

Comment: This solutions fixed my infra , where nginx was used as reverse proxy. ssl was enabled.. and wordpress was inside docker.

Comment: Im in ago 2023 and this save my day... thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

After changing the "Wordpress Address" and the "Site Adress" to `https`, and keeping `FORCE_SSL_ADMIN` set to `true`, I would make the `http` to `https` redirects occur above the code - so you're not relying on PHP/Wordpress to do it. If running Apache do it with `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

If Nginx there's lots of how-to's online. If you want to limit it to just your /blog/ or subdomain, you can refine the `RewriteCond`'s.

After that try logging in again. If you still get admin permission errors, try in Private Browsing mode to rule out a confused login cookie.

(Also in "Related" sidebar, found this thread where using `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` with `FORCE_SSL_ADMIN` caused exact same issues:  [Setting $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on' prevents access to wp-admin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/250240/setting-serverhttps-on-prevents-access-to-wp-admin?rq=1) )

Answer (score 2):

This Really Worked for me in AWS, Amazon Linux 2

WordPress LAMP + Wordpress

Added this Code at the top of the `wp-config.php`:

```
<?php
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https')
    $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Also search wp-setting.php file for `define('DISALLOW_FILE_MODS',true);` and delete it. Non of the above solutions worked for me except this one!

Comment: +1 UNEXPECTED, you are right, this really helpful, it's allow me re-enable updates for WordPress, thanks